# how can I setup @types for a third party react javascript module so I can access it from typescript and package it with webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack

There is a 3rd party all-javascript npm [scoped](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) package, let's call it @foo, with a module inside called bar. I wanted to use the react component @foo/bar/X from within my typescript .tsx file.  I immediately ran into "module not found" when I tried to `import X from '@foo/bar/X'`. How can I resolve this using [@types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) typescript to resolve the module X and get webpack to run without errors?

Answer (score 0):

My starting point was this introduction on how to how to use react and webpack with typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html. However, said instructions do not tackle the problem that the react component I want to use has no @types. So my first step is I needed to add @types.

There was one important nuance about the scoped module @foo/bar, which was that it broke all its subcomponents into individual sub modules like @foo/bar/X, @foo/bar/Y, and @foo/bar/Z with @foo/bar itself having no functionality. As we will see that was an important nuance which made solving this a bit trickier than if I had not had to import a scoped module into my typescript.

There is a [nice blog post here](https://medium.com/@chris_72272/migrating-to-typescript-write-a-declaration-file-for-a-third-party-npm-module-b1f75808ed2) about how to import a vanilla javascript into typescript. Unfortunately there is a shortcoming to the proposed approach. Namely, the idea of adding "index.d.ts' to a  src/@typings has two problems:

1. It works only for running the typescript compiler (tsc) locally. That is to say it will make tsc happy, by allowing tsc to resolve the module from your your local ".d.ts" file, but webpack will still fail with module not found.
2. The proposed approach didn't teach me how to deal with scoped modules which have different rules for how folders under @types are named

Whatever approach I tried, I knew I needed to have this import statement in my typescript file:

```
import X from '@foo/bar/X';

ReactDOM.render(
    <X/>,
    document.getElementById("example")
);
```

Somewhere, I needed to have the following in a ".d.ts" declarations file like index.d.ts, that much was obvious:

```
declare module '@foo/bar';
declare module '@foo/bar/X';
```

But running 'webpack' yielding `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@foo/bar/X'`

I decided to run the typescript compiler (tsc) with this flag to see the possible places where tsc would try to resolve the module.

```
tsc --traceresolution
```

Using the traceresolution flag I was able to see something very interesting: that the location under node_modules/@types where tsc searches was quite unexepected (and thereby where webpack searches, since webpack follows the same rules as tsc). It was expecting to find my index.d.ts file under `node_modules/@types/foo__bar` NOTE THE DOUBLE UNDERSCORE. That's right, for scope packages, you cannot have `node_modules/@types/@foo/bar/index.d.ts`. Instead you must use a single folder under @types named `foo__bar` with DOUBLE UNDERSCORE.

With this knowledge I created @types/foo__bar. I copied package.json from the @foo/bar module into @types/foo__bar. I cleaned out all the scripts and other useless stuff that the @types would not need, and stripped it down to this:

```
{
  "name": "@types/@sfoo/bar",
  "version": "2.6.0",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3",
    "react-dom": "^16",
    "styled-components": "^3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
...
  },

  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6"
  },
  "gitHead": "ac0288aaa47a4f15e56db3a5eff4424fb7905419",
  "main": "",
  "types": "index"
}
```

But yet there was one more problem! Even after tsc could resolve my @types, webpack still yielded `module not found: can't resolve @foo/bar`. So why the heck can't webpack find it? Again, I found a flag that could show me more:

```
webpack --verbose
```

But here I had less luck since the webpack rules were just like the typescript rules for module resolution. However from the --verbose output I did notice that one file webpack was interested in was node_modules/@foo/bar/index.js. However, the bar module lacked any index.js since it was really just an empty enclosing module around submodules like @foo/bar/X. Whether this is a bug or a feature of webpack, I don't know, but ADDING AN EMPTY index.js to node_modules/@foo/bar pacified webpack, and my simple example now worked with component X displayed in the browser when I loaded the HTML page.